# Assembly.Load duplicates the Assembly when loaded into a new AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

I currently have a problem where if I set up a new App Domain and use `AppDomain.Load`, The Assembly gets loaded twice (Once into the new App Domain, and once into the default App Domain)

The code I am using to load the Assembly is as follows:

```
AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain(_dllname);

                AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
                assemblyName.CodeBase = directory + _dllname;

                Assembly a = dom.Load(assemblyName);
```

When I use this code the `Assembly` loads correctly into my new `AppDomain` (with the same name as the dll) but for some reason, always loads into the default `AppDomain` (in this occasion, `IQUS_Main.vshost.exe`)

Here is a screenshot of the issue, immediately after the `dom.Load` line:

[image: Duplicate App Domain]

Comment: Isn't this covered by the [fine manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/36az8x58)? "If the current AppDomain object represents application domain A, and the Load method is called from application domain B, the assembly is loaded into both application domains."

Comment: You should be using a `MarshalByRefObject` object (in a secondary domain) that loads the assembly for you on your behalf.  Though your current code is loading the assembly into the 2nd domain, you return a reference to the primary into `a`