# Memory consumption by shared libraries in multiple IIS Apps

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory, optimization

Lets say, I have few ASP.NET Applications deployed in IIS. They all have some common libraries (i.e. System.Web.Http.dll, etc) referenced from the global assembly cache (GAC).

When the applications start up, does separate copies of those shared libraries load in the memory? What sort of optimization we can try to reduce the memory footprint?

Comment: Your best hope is to merge them all into a single application. Otherwise, different applications go to different `AppDomain` and assemblies won't be able to share. This thread shows the basics, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213755/assembly-load-duplicates-the-assembly-when-loaded-into-a-new-appdomain while you need to learn ASP.NET process model to understand the rest.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, I am talking about shared libraries like System.Web.dll which is installed as part of .NET in GAC.

Comment: Then you need to learn even more things. GAC is the file cache, and sharing assemblies in GAC won't help "reduce the memory footprint", as multiple applications (aka AppDomains) will load multiple copies of the same assemblies into memory. To assert that, attach a debugger  (like WinDbg) to the worker process (or use Process Explorer), and check modules loaded.